# Initializing a multidimensional with many default values

Tags: javascript, array

I need to create a \${n} \times {n}\$ multidimensional array filled with default values.

Right now, I'm using this code:

```
//--- how many columns?
var colNumber = 10;
//--- how many rows?
var rowNumber = 20;

//--- default value
var defaultValue = "default";

var defRow = [];
var defaultArray = [];

for(var x = 0; x < colNumber; x++){
    defRow.push(defaultValue);   
}
for(var x = 0; x < rowNumber; x++){
    defaultArray.push(defRow);
}
console.log(defaultArray);
```

find fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g5w4025p/)

Is there any better approach to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there's a better approach. The problem you have here is that each row is the same value, so a change to one row will be seen in all rows. For example, I added the following to your code to illustrate this:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(defaultArray));
defaultArray[5][5] = "Fubar";
console.log(JSON.stringify(defaultArray));
```

This should change the value in the middle of the 'matrix', but instead the result is:

```
"[["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"],
["default","default","default","default","default","Fubar","default","default","default","default"]]"
```

You need to have a fresh array instance for each row.

Even though it is mundane, the logical way to do it is:

```
var defaultArray = [];

for(var x = 0; x < rowNumber; x++){
    var defRow = [];
    for(var y = 0; y < colNumber; y++){
        defRow.push(defaultValue);   
    }
    defaultArray.push(defRow);
}
```

---

**Edit:** [Based on the benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/59) for my browser (Firefox), a decrementing while-loop is much faster than alternatives. I would use:

```
var defaultArray = [];

for(var row = rowNumber - 1; row >= 0; row--){
    var defRow = [];
    for(var col = colNumber - 1; col >= 0; col--){
        defRow[col] = defaultValue;   
    }
    defaultArray[row] = defRow);
}
```

By working backwards over the array you reduce the amount of space allocations that happen as the array grows. Here's the results of that benchmark for me:

[image: Benchmarks]

Comment: well noted, I totally forgot that. Do you think `defRow.slice(0)` would be better to clone the entire row in one time instead of using the second nested `for` loop?

Comment: See [This SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20547803/1305253) which has mixed recommendations, including `defRow.slice()`, `defRow.slice(0)`, and a while loop counting backwards. Based on [the benchmarks here](http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/59) the while-loop is much, much faster for me.

Comment: Fixed the benchmark. The array `b` wasn't initialised in the test, so it was overwriting properties that already existed instead of adding properties. Now the while loop gets a reasonable result. http://jsperf.com/new-array-vs-splice-vs-slice/60

Answer (score 5):

From a once over:

- I tend to call `colNumber` -> `colCount` or `columns`
- It is considered better practice to group your variables in 1 comma-chained `var`
- You declared `var x` twice, this is not needed, and does most likely not what you think it does.
- My nitpicker side cringes to see **default**Array, **default**Value and **def**Row
- Your comments are too much, comments must be worth their space, prime offender:
  `//--- default value`
  `var defaultValue = "default";`

My counter-proposal woul be:

```
var columnCount = 10,
    rowCount = 20,
    column, row;

var defaultArray = [],
    defaultValue = "default",
    defaultRow = [];

//Not the most fastest way, I defer to Rolf for that part
for(row = 0; row < rowCount ; row++){
    defaultRow = [];
    for(column = 0; column < columnCount ; column++){
        defaultRow[column] = defaultValue;   
    }
    defaultArray[row] = defaultRow;
}

console.log(defaultArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a function that creates an array, then just use it to create an array for each item in the array:

```js
function createArray(len, val) {
  var a = [];
  var func = typeof val === 'function';
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    a[i] = func ? val() : val;
  }
  return a;
}

var defaultArray = createArray(20, createArray.bind(this, 10, "default"));

// Display in StackExchange snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(defaultArray));
```

Note: The `bind` method isn't supported in IE8, but you can just use a function expression instead if you need to support it. The `jQuery` library also has a replacement (`$.proxy`), and I guess many other libraries have one too.